# JSP - Twitter Bootstrap modal form processing

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

I want to proceed a modal form with jsp. My Problem is, that the buttons is in another div, therefore the servlet ´/user´ does not get rendered.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/user" method="post">
          <fieldset>
              <div class="control-group">
                 <!-- Text input-->
                 <label class="control-label" for="input01">Email:</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                           <input name="email" placeholder="email" class="input-xlarge" type="text"value="<%=request.getParameter("email")%>">
                     </div>
             </div>

             <div class="control-group">
                  <!-- Text input-->
                  <label class="control-label" for="input01">Password:</label>
                         <div class="controls">
                              <input name="password" placeholder="password" class="input-xlarge" type="text" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>">
                         </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```

How to write it properly that I can use the buttons in the other div to submit the form?

Comment: Is there a season why you can't have the `submit` button inside the form?

Comment: you can put an id attribute on your form and on the onclick event of your button you can call the document.forms["formId"].submit() or jQuery $('#formId').submit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put an id attribute on your form and on the onclick event of your button you can call the document.forms["formId"].submit() or jQuery $('#formId').submit()

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" action="/user" method="post"> //add id attr
```

try this on your button:

```
<input type='button' value='submit' onclick='document.forms["myForm"].submit();'/>
```

or with jQuery:

```
<input type='button' value='submit' onclick='$("#myForm").submit();'/>
```